# exponentiate a matrix in perl

Tags: perl, matrix, exponent

I'm looking for a function to exponentiate a matrix using perl.  I've searched CPAN but can't seem to find anything suitable. Does anyone know of a suitable package, or easy function?

For example, for the following matrix ($m):

```
$m = [[-1.85294,0.36417,1.34865,0.14012],
      [0.13385,-0.70885,0.16502,0.40998],
      [0.48588,0.16174,-0.77471,0.12709],
      [0.13424,1.06859,0.33797,-1.54081]];
```

e^m ~=

```
0.25438971 0.2029723 0.4580481 0.08458940
0.07460393 0.6061030 0.1588883 0.16040370
0.16502112 0.1557330 0.6025270 0.07671839
0.08103971 0.4180838 0.2040153 0.29685570
```

Comment: How about http://search.cpan.org/~ellipse/PDL-LinearAlgebra-0.06/Trans/trans.pd#mexp or http://www.davideous.com/matrixexp/matrix.pm?

Answer (score 1):

PDL will handle this, as @J.D. points out.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDL;
use PDL::LinearAlgebra::Trans;
use PDL::IO::Dumper;

my $m = pdl [[-1.85294,0.36417,1.34865,0.14012],
             [0.13385,-0.70885,0.16502,0.40998],
             [0.48588,0.16174,-0.77471,0.12709],
             [0.13424,1.06859,0.33797,-1.54081]];

my $new = mexp $m;

print sdump $new;
```

Result:

```
{my($VAR1);
my($PDL_140600590505856) = (double(0.254389714179579,0.202972289234997,0.458048094091295,0.08458940315894629,0.0746039289026906,0.606102994157082,0.158888283526803,0.160403695685552,0.165021120118487,0.155733015860466,0.602527027489139,0.07671838765811791,0.08103970821403091,0.418083774202018,0.204015347133539,0.296855703714981)->reshape(4,4));


$VAR1 = $PDL_140600590505856;

}
```

The bit inside the `double()` function is the result matrix.

Comment: That does the trick. It seems to print three warnings about subrouintes being redfined.  I'm sure its nothing to worry about, but do you know of a way to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: Strange. I didn't get any warnings running it under perl 5.14.2. What version of Perl and PDL are you using?

Comment: I'm running perl v5.12.4, but there could be something up with my installation of PDL (mostly installed using apt-get on Ubuntu, but PDL::LinearAlgebra::Trans installed from source).  I'll investigate...